Application of Hurwitz's Theorem
Let $f_n$ be a sequence of entire functions converging uniformly on compact subsets to $f$. Suppose that for every $n$ the zeros of $f_n$ lie on the real axis. Show that $f$ is either identically zero or only has zeros on real axis.
My attempt:
Suppose $f$ is not identically 0, then define a compact set $K = [-R,R] \times [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$ with $R>0$ to be determined. Bu Hurwitz's theorem $$Z(f_n) = \int_{C_n} \frac{f'_n}{f_n} dz = \int_{C_n} \frac{f'}{f} dz = Z(f)$$ for large $n$, where $Z(f_n)$ is the number of zeros of $f_n$ inside $C_n$. Then since the number of zeros is integer valued, it must be constant after some $n$ so $f_n$ must have finitely many zeros. Thus we can choose $R$ such that all zeros of $f_n$ are inside $K$. Since $f_n$ has zeros on the real axis, we can take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{n}$ so as $\epsilon \to 0$, $K \to [-R,R] \subset \mathbb{R}$. Thus $Z(f) = Z(f_n)$ on $K$ for arbitrary $\epsilon$ implies that $Z(f_n) = Z(f)$ on the real axis. Thus $f$ must have zeros only on the real axis.
Does this argument work? I am not completely certain I can take $\epsilon$ to 0 since then we have a closed curve with empty interior. Let me know if there are any holes in my argument or if there is another way to show this result.

wouldn't it be easier to run it as a contradiction?  E.g. suppose $p\in \mathbb C-\mathbb R$ and $f(p)=0$ for non-constant $f$.  Then $f$ is defined on a domain so there is a closed ball $\overline B\big(p,\delta\big)$ on which $f$ is defined and $f$ is non-zero on $\partial \overline B\big(p,\delta\big)$ for any $\delta \gt 0$ small enough [insist $\delta \lt \vert p\vert$]  and we have $Z(f_n) \lt Z(f)$ for all $n$ contradicting Hurwitz. Conclude if $f$ is non-constant, then $p\in \mathbb R$.

Thanks very much. That is a neat proof!

it should say "[insist $\delta\lt \vert \text{im}(p)\vert$]"... that way $\overline B\big(p,\delta\big)\cap \mathbb  R=\big{\big}$, but otherwise is right
